# shoulda matchers with_message bug for custom validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, rspec, shoulda

I have a user model that requires a password with at least one uppercase letter. My spec is written as follows:

```
subject { User.new }
it { should_not allow_value("test123$").for(:password).with_message("password requires an uppercase letter (\"test123$\")") }
```

However, this spec returns the following failure:

```
Expected errors to include ["password requires an uppercase letter (\"test123$\")"] when password is set to "test123$", got errors: ["password requires an uppercase letter (\"test123$\")"]
```

It looks to me like the errors array clearly includes the correct message. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
Here's the validation that I'm trying to spec:

```
[
  [/[A-Z]/, "requires an uppercase letter"],
  [/[a-z]/, "requires a lowercase letter"],
  [/[0-9]/, "requires a number"],
  [/[^\w]/, "requires a special character"]
].each do |(format, message)|
  validates :password, :format => {:with => format,
    :message => message},
    :allow_blank => true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only conclude that you're executing code that is different than what you've shown. Your RSpec failure message indicates that you're expecting the errors array to include an array containing the string in question rather than expecting it to include the string itself. Could it be that this error message is resulting from running a spec with contained `....with_message(["..."])` instead of what you've shown?

The associated shoulda code is pretty straightforward.  See line 120 of https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/d680e7d47ba0d0bc6eba888cc4648f65b61ac2cf/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/allow_value_matcher.rb

Comment: I've added the code for the validation responsible for producing this error message. Is there something funky going on there?

Comment: You need to add that to your question as code so that it's readable.

Comment: Sorry about that, it should be fixed now.

Comment: I wasn't questioning your validation code, I was questioning your spec itself, since the seemingly spurious square brackets were around the expectation in the error message.

Comment: My spec doesn't contain any brackets in the parameter for the with_message. I ran the same test that I pasted in my original question.

Comment: I'm not trying to be argumentative :-), but I just installed shoulda on my machine and ran a test in the same format and there were no brackets used after "errors to include". Is it possible that you had brackets in any earlier version of this test and you're running that earlier version uninentionally? Could you maybe put some debug code in the version of the test you are editing now just to confirm that your edits make it to the test results? Then maybe you could share the whole spec?